# aurelia/skeleton-plugin cant run test on custum element

Tags: karma-runner, aurelia

i have created an aurelia plugin using the skelton-plugin https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-plugin i am now looking at writing unit tests for it.
i am stuggling to get a unit test running for a custom element ive added to the project. i started with the 'testing a custom element' example from http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/testing/latest/testing-components/3

template:

```
<template>
  <div class="firstName">${firstName}</div>
</template>
```

vm

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyComponent {
  @bindable firstName;
}
```

i added this to the src folder.

my test code is

```
import {StageComponent} from 'aurelia-testing';
import {bootstrap} from 'aurelia-bootstrapper';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component;

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = StageComponent
      .withResources('my-component')
      .inView('<my-component first-name.bind="firstName"></my-component>')
      .boundTo({ firstName: 'Bob' });
  });

  it('should render first name', done => {
    component.create(bootstrap).then(() => {
      const nameElement = document.querySelector('.firstName');
      expect(nameElement.innerHTML).toBe('Bob');
      done();
    }).catch(e => { console.log(e.toString()) });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    component.dispose();
  });
});
```

i jspm installed aurelia-bootstrapper and aurelia-testing to get it running.
im now getting the error

```
Error{stack: '(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/my-component.js
```

so it looks like karma cant find my component. i checked the karma.config file and the jspm  loadFiles: ['test/setup.js', 'test/unit/**/*.js'], looks correct.
has any one run into a similar issue?

Comment: updated .withResources('my-component') to .withResources('src/my-component') and now the error is error{stack: '(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/src/my-component.html'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the issue.

in karma.config.js file needed to change 
serveFiles: ['src/**/*.*'] 
to 
serveFiles: ['src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.html']